# Kivy Spinner - Values Size

Tags: list, kivy, spinner, text-size

Is there a way to change the text size from the `values` argument within `Spinner`? I've found that I can change the height and width of the dropdown boxes and change the size of the "label" (Layer). But is there a way to change the text size of both `heads` and `all`?

```
Spinner:
    id: spinner_lry
    text: 'Layer'
    values:['heads', 'all']
    size_hint_y: None
    height: 50
    font_size: 20
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the options in a `Spinner` are displayed using the `SpinnerOption` class (just a `Button`) by default. You can set a different class to display the options using `option_cls` atribute, and specify the `font_size` for that class, like this in your `kv`:

```
<MyOption@SpinnerOption>:
    font_size: 50

Spinner:
    id: spinner_lry
    text: 'Layer'
    option_cls: "MyOption"
    values:['heads', 'all']
    size_hint_y: None
    height: 50
    font_size: 20
```

If you want the options to inherit the `font_size` of the `Spinner`, you can define a new `Spinner` class extension:

```
class MySpinner(Spinner):
    def on_font_size(self, spinner_instance, new_font_size):
        # this method is modelled after the _update_dropdown_size() method of Spinner
        dp = self._dropdown
        if not dp:
            return

        container = dp.container
        if not container:
            return
        
        for item in container.children[:]:
            item.font_size = new_font_size
```

The new `on_font_size()` method adjust the `font_size` of the options whenever the `font_size` of `MpSpinner` changes. You also need to adjust your `kv`:

```
<MyOption@SpinnerOption>:
    height: self.texture_size[1] * 1.1

MySpinner:
    id: spinner_lry
    text: 'Layer'
    option_cls: "MyOption"
    values:['heads', 'all']
    size_hint_y: None
    height: self.font_size * 1.5
    font_size: 20
```

This uses the new `MySpinner` class and the `MyOption` class now adjusts its `height` based on its `texture_size`.

Comment: Sweet! Thank you!

Comment: How do I pass the value of `ids.spinner_lry.font_size` to `SpinnerOption`? For example, I want something like `font_size: ids.spinner_lry.font_size*2.5`.